# Is there something like the Linux ptrace syscall in Windows?

Tags: windows, ptrace

Reading *[Monitoring certain system calls done by a process in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process)*, I'm wondering about a Windows equivalent to the [ptrace](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/programmatical#Adjective) system call or a programmatical workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ETW to trace system calls.  When starting the trace, in EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES, you can add EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_SYSTEMCALL flag to EnableFlags.  This enables SysCallEnter and SysCallLeave events, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964809(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: But SysCallEnter require Vista or Windows Server 2008, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible with ETW to find out the arguments to system calls?