# Is there something like Linux ptrace syscall in Windows XP/2003?

Tags: windows, debugging, ptrace

Reading *[Monitoring certain system calls done by a process in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process)*, I'm wondering about a Windows equivalent to the [ptrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) system call or a programmatical workaround.

I had an answer in *[Is there something like the Linux ptrace syscall in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865106/is-there-something-like-linux-ptrace-syscall-in-windows)*, but it requires a recent Windows version.

Comment: One thing to note here is that unlike linux, windows syscalls are undocumented and may change between versions. You might be better off setting a breakpoint in a higher level DLL...

Comment: Well `ptrace` is a very "versatile" function. There are functions for many of ptrace's functionalities in Windows, but there's not one single function that does them all (this is arguably a good thing). What exactly do you aim to do?

Answer (score 2):

[Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) is a [Sysinternals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals) utility for doing that.