# In Windows, how can I trace in C which files a child process reads and writes?

Tags: c, windows

My goal is to determine when executing a command, precisely which files it reads and writes. On Linux I can do this using [ptrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) (with work, akin to what [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) does) and on [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) and MacOS I can do this with the [ktrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ktrace) system command. What would you use to obtain this information on Windows?

My research so far suggests that I either use the debugger interface (similar to ptrace in many ways) or perhaps [ETW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/event-tracing-for-windows). A third alternative is to interpose a DLL to intercept system calls as they are made.  Unfortunately, I don't have the experience to guess as to how challenging each of these approaches will be.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably it is sufficient with a GUI tool? Try Windows Internals (filemon).

Comment: how about using resource monitor in windows 7 or process explorer

Comment: No, a GUI tool is not sufficient, I have to be able to do this from my program, which is written in C (but could use C++ if needed).

Comment: Look at [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours)

Comment: This is a pretty lousy functional specification.  Doesn't sound like it needs anything more than auditing.  Use the group policy editor to turn it on and read the event log.

Comment: @Nikerboker,  I looked at Detours,  but am working on an unfundend open source project and don't care for the free-version limitation to 32-bit progrms.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to use the Chromium sandbox to accomplish this with arbitrary child processes.  https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox/Sandbox-FAQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suggested, this is a fairly simple task to solve with API hooking with DLL injection.

This is a pretty good article about the application: *[API hooking revealed](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed)*

I believe you can find more recent articles about the issue.

However, you probably need to use C++ to implement such a utility. By the way, programs can disable DLL injection. For example, I weren't able to use this approach on the trial version of [Photoshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop).

So, you may want to check if you can inject DLL files in the process you want with an existing solution before you start writing your own.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it seems there is no easy way to intercept file level operations on Windows.

Here are some hints:

- you could try to use [FileMon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor#FileMon) from [Sysinternals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals) if it is enough for your needs, or try to look at the source of the tool
- you could make use of commercial software like [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) - beware, I never used that myself and I'm not sure it really meets your needs

If you want a better understanding and are not frightened at doing it *by hand*, the Windows way of intercepting file I/O is using a [File System Filter Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641617). In fact, there is a [FilterManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541591) embedded in Windows system that can forward all file system calls to *minifilters*.

To build it, the interface with the system is provided by the FilterManager, and you have just (...) to code and install the *minifilter* that does the actual filtering - beware again never tested that ...

Comment: I've started looking into the file system minifilters, but have some difficulty seeing how they could help.  It looks like the filter needs to be installed to the system, perhaps using administrative privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look to the article *[CDirectoryChangeWatcher - ReadDirectoryChangesW all wrapped up](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/950/CDirectoryChangeWatcher-ReadDirectoryChangesW-all)*.

It is a very old, but running, way to watch directory changes.

Comment: It looks to me that this approach doesn't allow to find out which process performed the modifications.  Also, it looks like it doesn't provide a mechanism to determine which files were read.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft owns a bunch of tools called [Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx). There is a program called [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) that will show you all the file accesses for a particular process. This is very likely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check this particular Stack Overflow question out for your question... This might help you:
*[Is there something like the Linux ptrace syscall in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865106/is-there-something-like-linux-ptrace-syscall-in-windows)*

Also, if you are running lower versions like [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) then you should check out *[Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)*.

Also, I would like you to check this out...
*[Monitoring certain system calls done by a process in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process-in-windows)*