# Monitoring IO like Sysinternals' ProcMon

Tags: filesystems, io, monitoring, procmon

How does the Process Monitor from Sysinternals monitor file IO activity like it does? If you enable the advanced information, you can see that calls that were previously shown as CreateFile are now shown as IRP_MJ_CREATE which suggests that it hooks some rather low level stuff. Does anyone know exactly what it hooks/how it works?

Comment: It is my understanding that a kernel mode driver is used/required to do what Process Monitor does.

Comment: Where could I learn how to write one?

Comment: Process Monitor needs no install so I'd be surprised if it actually installs a filter driver or something. As to your question where you can learn this. Would like to know myself, but so far I've looked at this book: http://www.amazon.com/Windows-System-Internals-Classic-Reprints/dp/0976717514/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1297344046&sr=8-1 that may shed some light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your answer is with [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process)