# Windows 7 explorer.exe file api

Tags: api, windows-7, explorer

Does anyone know which windows-APIs are used by the explorer.exe to find the files of a directory?

In Windows XP it used FindFirstFileW() and FindNextFileW(), but on windows vista and 7 the explorer does not use them anymore...

Comment: FindFirstFileTransacted() perhaps, first available at Vista.  You should never care.

Comment: Nope... it seems like it's also not used by explorer.exe...

Answer (score 0):

The newer Windows versions automatically sort the Files in a Folder when opening them.
It is possible to restore the old behaviour.

A description how to do that is [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-full-row-select-explorer-windows-7/)

Comment: and how does this answer my question? I wanted to know what APIs are used, and not how the files are sorted...

Comment: I don't have the source code for the Explorer so try contacting the microsoft support hotline. You might get more info what the program does when you monitor the system calls like it was mentioned in this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process