# Keeping a log of system calls

Tags: windows, kernel, 32-bit

I need to know if there is anyway to redirect some data of a system call (like for copy_file() with parameters such as old path, new path, etc.) to a log file for each and every time that function will be invoked.

Comment: Which operating system is this for?

Comment: for windows platform ,32 bits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitoring certain system calls done by a process in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/timdiels/sysintercept

"sysintercept allows you to intercept and modify win32 system calls done by a process. sysintercept provides a CLI. Aim is to allow rewriting paths, translating keyboard input, ... various things for improved compatibility."

If you want to know how to intercept system calls yourself programmatically, you can inspect the source code.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there is Process Monitor (ProcMon) tool which logs system calls such as File I/O.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: i am concern with the mechanism behind logging the system call,what i willing to know is that how the above or http://www.trisunsoft.com/windows-explorer-tracker/ , or any other software is working,how these software providing the logs.there must be some kind of coding which enables the software to interrupt the system calls when they have being called and then redirecting data from the same call to a log file.

Comment: @HimanshuBaunthiyal: That program works by installing a filesystem filter driver and watching file operations. It doesn't intercept syscalls.