# Is there any way to hook a window api globally?

Tags: winapi, hook, dll-injection

e.g. hook a write file api so that every process write file must through my function's filter.

I only know a hook function `SetWindowsHookEx` but so sad it only hook for global key events.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

Not from user mode but you can in kernel mode with a file system filter driver. There's a new model, the Filter Manager Model, which reduces the complexity of developing a file system filter driver. See "Filter Manager and Minifilter Driver Architecture" in the MSDN.