# How to find what certificate an application is using

Tags: certificate

I’m needing to know what certificate is currently being used for an application.

I’ve tried using procmon but could not find a certificate store location.

Powershell also doesn’t have any native cmdlets that show me the information.

I would assume at some point the executable would have to encrypt the traffic and would have to open the cert or read the cert - is there a way to easily query this?

Windows Env
Https traffic

Sorry if this is a silly question :)

Comment: Used for what? HTTPS traffic?  I assume that you are talking about Windows here ...

Comment: @StephenC correct on both accounts.

Comment: This might be the way to find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839.  Monitor the I/O events for your app to find out what files it is opening and look for something that opens a cert store.